# Go to activity without starting it upon clicking on notification

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications

Following the Android tutorial on Notification https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html I'm able to display a Notification.
What I do want, which is not explain in the article, is how to go to the activity without starting it.
In fact I have an application with a couple of Activities. As soon as I enter one of those activities, a permanent Notification is shown which only disappears when the user leaves that activity.
If the user then clicks on the Notification while my application is not on screen, I want the activity to be resumed without restarting it. The activity runs a counter. That's why it shouldn't be restarted.

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I manage to solve the problem.
In the manifest.xml file set `android:launchMode="singleTop"` for that activity. And then you build the notification as follows:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_directions_run_white_24dp).setContentTitle("My " + 
                    "notification").setContentText("Hello World!");
    // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, PlayActivity.class);
    resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, resultIntent, 
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService
            (Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

I haven't gone with using the `SharedPreferences` because the whole process of retrieving the counter value and restarting the activity could hold the counter for some time which may make lose its accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the activity to be resumed without restarting it. The activity runs a counter. That's why it shouldn't be restarted.

Well, you have to save the counter state during `onPause()` method and restore it during `onResume()` method.

> How to save the state?

You can save the counter value into `SharedPreferences`. That will do the magic for you. cheers :)